# how to inflate one layout for sometime and then another?

Tags: android, layout

I have a single layout and i use it for displaying two different instances. Please see the code below, I guess this logic should work but it's not working.

```
setContentView(R.layout.notification);
//Notify user if Battery level is low
        if (iBatlevel <= 50)
        {

            ImageButton CamButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            CamButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ImageButton PButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            PButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ProgressBar _batPB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            _batPB.setProgress(iBatlevel);
            _batPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView _batText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notifymsg);
            _batText.setText("!!! Low Battery !!!\n"+Integer.toString(iBatlevel)+"%"+" remaining");

            //Wait for 4 seconds
            Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() {                    
                } 
            }, 400000); 
        }   
        /*****************************************************************************************/


        //To check whether SDcard is present are not
        boolean isSDCardPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    //    Intent intent = null;
        if(isSDCardPresent)
        {
        //  setContentView(R.layout.sdcard);
            ImageButton CamButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            CamButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ImageButton PButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            PButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ProgressBar _batPB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            _batPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Drawable warning_img = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.warning );
            TextView warning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notifymsg);
            warning.setText("SDcard not found !!!");
            warning_img.setBounds( 0, 0, 30, 30 );
            warning.setCompoundDrawables( warning_img, null, null, null );

            // intent = new Intent(this,SDcard.class);
            // startActivity(intent);
           // finish();
        }
```

If the battery is low, the corresponding layout should be displayed for some time and then the other, but though the battery loop is true I get only the SDcard view. Any idea how to go around?

Answer (score 0):

How I usually handle this problem is to inflate both instances into separate layouts with a common parent layout.  Then programmatically toggle the visibility of the layout I want to show depending on the battery state (or anything else).  One layout will always be VISIBLE while the other layout will always be GONE.